# send.keys(Keys.ENTER) is not working in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

browser=webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.screener.in/')

sbox = browser.switch_to.active_element

sbox.send_keys('Infosys Ltd')

sbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

The enter key is not working. I have tried using `.submit()` too but still isn't working. Please let me know if there is any other way to get it.

Comment: What exception you getting? What do you mean by not working?

Comment: Was the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Keys.ENTER` instead of `Keys.RETURN`

Answer (score 0):

switch_to may be unstable depending on browsers. Also, make sure `sbox` is visible before you interact with it. Try:

```
sbox['value'].send_keys('Infosys Ltd')
sbox['value'].send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Please accept&upvote if the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = "https://www.foodpanda.pk/restaurants/new?lat=24.9414896&lng=67.1676002&vertical=restaurants"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.screener.in/')

sbox = browser.switch_to.active_element

sbox.send_keys('Infosys Ltd')

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="dropdown-content visible"]')))
sbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

wait for the dropdown to be visible before sending the enter

imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: The key import is 'from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys'